# what this is smd sot23-6 marking code 63

Tags: surface-mount, touchscreen

i need help.

I have problem with resistive touchscreen 4 wire, I've replaced with a new touchscreen but it still doesn't work.
Capacitor & other part around ic is normal.

I think this ic damage.

[image]
[image]

Pin 1 to pin 1 touchscreen

Pin 2 to GND

Pin 3 to pin 2 touchscreen

Pin 4 to pin 3 touchscreen

Pin 5 to VCC 3.3V

Anyone know this ic?

Pin 6 to pin 4 touchscreen

Answer (score 3):

It'll be some form of quad TVS diode.

These usually have the VCC/GND as the middle two pins, and then the four corner pins are connected to IO lines to protect them from damaging ESD strikes.

---

A quick search for `SOT23-6 TVS 63`, and yep, it is a TVS diode array. Specifically it is the [NUP4201MR6](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nup4201mr6-d.pdf) from ON Semiconductor.

These are marked as shown below:

[image: Marking code from datasheet]

We can see the main device specific marking "63", and then to the right of that there is a letter rotated 90 degrees (in your case "C"), which matches the expected position of the date code for the device.

It also has the pin 1 marker in the correct place, and even the expected Pb-free microdot in the middle just above pin 2.