# Is there an alternative number for this IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

[image]

This circuit belongs to a car music system.

Comment: See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/589822/what-this-is-smd-sot23-6-marking-code-63).

Comment: As @Rohat mentions, this appears to be a duplicate of [what this is smd sot23-6 marking code 63](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/589822/what-this-is-smd-sot23-6-marking-code-63)

Comment: Why do we have a tag called "alternatives"...

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a NUP4201 or NUP4204 Transient Voltage
Suppressors.

Datasheet [here](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/nup4201mr6-d.pdf).

Photo of parts at seekic.com seems good match, with same rotated date code, and 2 id dots. [image: seekic.com].

The same part is sought (and identified) in this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/589822/what-this-is-smd-sot23-6-marking-code-63)